# How can I make the Photos app show the locations for my pictures?

Tags: photos, geolocation

How can I make the Photos app show the locations for my pictures?

I took many pictures while on a trip today, and would like to view the photo locations in the default "Photos" app.

I have a Microsoft Lumia 535 with "Use location info" turned on in "Camera settings".  I have the "Group my photos by time and location" setting turned on also in the "Photo settings".

Some of my other photos are grouped by date and location, which is what I want.  But the photos from today only show the date.

If I view the new photos in Lumia Storyteller, then I can see the location for the photos.

Is there a way to force the Photos app to refresh or update the photos so that I can see the location for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently,there is no method in Default Photos app.But sure you can use Storyteller app for your purpose.

Comment: Can you add any more information, like about how long it takes for the locations to eventually appear?